# Angular2 router.navigate reloads app

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have the following routes defined in my app ...

```
app.components.ts
@RouteConfig([
  {path:'/employees/...', name:'Employees', component:EmployeeComponent},
  ...

employee.component.ts
@RouteConfig([
  {path:'/', name:'EmployeeList', component:EmployeeListComponent, useAsDefault: true},
  {path:'/:id', name:'EmployeeDetail', component:EmployeeDetailComponent}
])
```

When I route from the EmployeeDetailComponent template ...

```
<button class="btn btn-default" [routerLink]="['EmployeeList']">Close</button>
```

the app routes to the employee listing page as expected.

However, when I route using router.navigate ...

```
// template
<button class="btn btn-default" (click)="save()">Save</button>

// EmployeeDetailComponent
saveEmployee() {
  this._employeeServer.updateEmployee(this.employee);
  this._router.navigate(['EmployeeList']);
}
```

the app routes the the employee listing (as expected) and then, a few moments later, the app reloads entirely (not as expected).

Any idea why router.navigate is behaving differently than routerLink?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use this directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: `click-stop-propagation`
  events: 'stopClick($event)'
})
class ClickStopPropagation {
  stopClick(event:Event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
}
```

and apply it this way:

```
<button class="btn btn-default"
    (click)="save()" click-stop-propagation>Save</button>
```

Another solution would be to pass the event to the `save` method:

```
<button class="btn btn-default"
    (click)="save($event)" click-stop-propagation>Save</button>
```

and use it to stop the event propagation:

```
save(event) {
  this._employeeServer.updateEmployee(this.employee);
  this._router.navigate(['EmployeeList']);
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Chose the option to pass the event in and it worked like a charm.  I needed to put the router.navigate after the event method calls for the route navigation to work.

Comment: for me `save($event)` works wheras `@directive events` doesn't. Thanks !

Comment: I found that if my <button> element is *inside* a <form> element that I need to stop propagation of the event. However, outside a <form> element, the (click) event does not cause the page to reload.

Answer (score 10):

`<button>` within `<form>` may be trying to submit. Try adding `<button type="button">` to prevent the  from submitting when clicking the button.

Comment: This seems like a preferable solution to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

While Thierry's answer with cancelling the event propagation worked for me, I found another solution;

Try wrapping the navigation in a timeout (of any duration)

```
...
setTimeout(() => {
    this._router.navigate(['EmployeeList']);
}, 0);
...
```

Whether or not you find this neater than including a click event is up for debate.  For me, I wanted to delay the navigation to wait for an animation anyway, and this way saved me from including an otherwise redundant click event.